# Particle Effect Hair - Grows randomly during animation

Tags: animation, rigging, particles

I have put together a basic human rig. I'm still new to this and this is one of the first, however it is my first attempt at making hair. I decided to try doing it with partcles after watching a video of how nicely it seemed to work with its own physics and all. It all seemed to work beautifully until I tried animating the rig with a completely basic head turn to see how the hair reacted. Instead of bouncing a bit, or even bouncing a bit much it did something a bit more extreme that I don't know how to explain... and so... I provided pictures.

[image]

My files for particles:

[image]
[image]

This only happens when he is in motion. Still shots render nicely as such

[image]

Comment: just a thought, does unticking the *Hair Dynamics* checkbox fix it?

Comment: Unticking the Hair Dynamics does indeed fix it. However doesnt that make it so it will no longer bob at all? Making it stiff and solid.

Comment: Yes, however we now know that it is the *Hair Dynamics* settings that are causing the issue. You can now try changing some settings and noticing what helps/makes it worse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lower *Stiffness* value in the hair dynamics settings (less than 2) for short hair.

[image: Hair Stiffness]